# Sumifs across multiple workbooks without VBA

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to sum of workers and sales.  I have 2 workbooks right now.  Workbook A has a "Names" column and a "Sales" while Workbook B has a "Names" column and a "Profit" column.  The "Names" columns are not in the same order between the two workbooks.  I am looking to find the sum of profits in Workbook B, of all the workers in Workbook A that has more than 10 sales.  So something like =SUMIFS('[WorkbookB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B, '[WorkbookA.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B > 10, '[WorkbookA.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A = '[WorkbookB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A).

I've seen a few posts about sumproducts and indirects but I'm not sure how that works so I apologize if this is an easy solution that I should have found.

I also know I can do a simple Vlookup to match the profits from Workbook B onto Workbook A and then do a sum from there but in this scenario, I can't display profits and names and sales all together.

Comment: The vlookup you mentioned - could you do that but hide the column and lock the worksheet? That way it would be serving the purpose but invisible to anyone without the password. Because really that's by far the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: *I am looking to find the sum of profits in Workbook B, of all the workers in Workbook A that has more than 10 sales* what about of using first COUNTIF to check if sales>10 and if true, then SUMIF?